# How can I get the position of the element which is at the bottom of the current screen in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in Android and surprisingly I did not find the solution to this problem online.

I have 1 textview (of Questions) in a RecyclerView and I am using an adapter to bind n number of questions into it.

Suppose I have 20 questions on the whole in the recyclerView, how will I get the position of the element which is on the bottom of the current screen (Not the last question, but just the position of the bottom question on the current screen when the view loads up)?

The length of the questions will be dynamic so always the same nth question won't be at the bottom of the screen on the first load.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionviewelement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
    android:textColor="@color/color_question"
    android:textSize="@dimen/settings_act_box_question_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
    android:scrollbarSize="2.5dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="75dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try this lines of code?

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

Comment: Yes I implemented this. It is giving value of -1 when there is 3rd question on the bottom.